# How to cancel specific one element at external CSS?

Tags: css, webkit

[image]

It use from external CSS file.(google MDL)

And I want to cancel just **-webkit-flex** element.
How can I cancel only that line?

Comment: have you tried to just reset the display value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Removing A Style**

If you want to remove a single specific style that is being applied to an element, you can simply set that style to an empty string :

```
// This would remove your specific style (i.e. -webkit-flex-wrap)
$('{selector}').css('{style}','');
```

This should remove the style entirely [as mentioned in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) :

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied,

**Setting Its Default**

If you simply want to set it to it's default value, you could setting its value to `initial` (i.e. `display: initial`) or you should consider what value you *want* it to have and use that.

**Consider Overriding**

If you are already using these styles, then it may simply be easier to just override them to define the values you want to use :

```
.mdl-navigation {
     display: {your-preferred-value}!important;
}
```

Comment: really good advice. but there are three `display` elements. Shoud I just re-write other two values??